# `justify-content: space-around` not working

Tags: html, css

**I just want to know that if we can adjust the space in `space-around` tag with padding**

I want to insert space between the HTML links in the second part of the header. I tried by putting `justify-content: space-around;` in the `ul` tag, but it did not worked.

This is the image of my output:

[image: My Output]

I don't think `justify-content` will not work. Can anyone help me? I also tried the three types of `justify-content` spaces in them, but I found no change.

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: Alata;
}
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.navbarlogo {
    height: 50px;
}
.logo-part {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.alinks {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex: 1;
    background: chocolate;
}
.ilinks {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alata">
  <link rel="icon" href="../Assets/cap.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">
  <title>Lonavala</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
  <div class="logo-part">
    <img class="navbarlogo" src="../Assets/cap.png" alt="logo">
    <h3>LONAVALA</h3>
  </div>
  <ul class="alinks">
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: Alata;
}
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.navbarlogo {
    height: 50px;
}
.logo-part {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.alinks {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex: 1;
    background: chocolate;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.ilinks {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alata">
  <link rel="icon" href="../Assets/cap.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">
  <title>Lonavala</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
  <div class="logo-part">
    <img class="navbarlogo" src="../Assets/cap.png" alt="logo">
    <h3>LONAVALA</h3>
  </div>
  <ul class="alinks">
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used "justify-content: space-between;" in UL tag css.

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content: space-between` works if you add it to the `ul.alinks` element. However, you may consider `space-around` since it adds space around each element - this give the first and last elements a bit of space from the edge of the container.

`space-between` or `space-around` works.

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: Alata;
}
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.navbarlogo {
    height: 50px;
}
.logo-part {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.alinks {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex: 1;
    background: chocolate;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.ilinks {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alata">
  <link rel="icon" href="../Assets/cap.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">
  <title>Lonavala</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
  <div class="logo-part">
    <img class="navbarlogo" src="../Assets/cap.png" alt="logo">
    <h3>LONAVALA</h3>
  </div>
  <ul class="alinks">
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li ><a class="ilinks" href="#">HTML</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```